# Using MockMvc inside of @BeforeAll static method

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, mockmvc

I am writing some integration tests in which I need to send in an api call to create a resource and then perform subsequent api calls based on that resource. I wanted to send the first call inside my @BeforeAll method.

In my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ExampleResourceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @BeforeAll
    private void createExampleResource() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();

        requestBody.put("email", "example@email.com");
        requestBody.put("username", "example");
        requestBody.put("firstName", "Example");
        requestBody.put("lastName", "Name");
        requestBody.put("password", "@password123");

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = gson.toJson(requestBody);

        mockMvc.perform(
                    post("/api/v1/resourcename")
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .content(json));
    }

    // More stuff...
}
```

However, the method annotated @BeforeAll method is not being called before I run the tests in the class.

As I understand from trying to find a solution, @BeforeAll methods need to be static. However, then I wouldn't be able to use my injected MockMvc. I've also tried annotating my test class with
`@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`, but I've faced no luck with that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was on junit 4 and needed to use @BeforeClass to be able to call it. I ended up instead using an @Before method and just using a boolean value to check if the call had already been made.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `@BeforeAll` should not be private but you have added that.
That is the reason it is not invoking your method.

Refer:
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, but it looks like it still will not work. The docs you sent reinforced that BeforeAll has to be on a static method. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to access my mockmvc from a static method when it is injected.

Comment: cool. Did you tried by adding `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` in your class and remove the private modifier.. ?